# exercise 1.7.5 of Basic Algebra I Jacobson

Tags: abstract-algebra

let $H$ and $K$ be two subgroups of a group $G$. 
Show that the set of maps $x \rightarrow hxk, h \in H, k \in K$ is a group of transformations of the set $G$.
Show that the orbit of $x$ relative to this group is the set 
$HxK = ${$ hxk|h \in H, k \in K\ $}. This is called *the double coset of x relative to the pair(H, K)*.
Show that if G is finite then $|HxK|=|H|[K:x^{-1}Hx\cap K]$.

---

btw I am so confused about the proof, as in this book, it seems the author just show the proof but I do not know how he gets the idea.

Comment: It seems to me as these are 3 parts of excersise

Answer (score 0):

The first two parts are quite straightforward. Let me elaborate a bit on the last statement.

*Proof*:
Since $K$ is a subgroup, it is easy to verify that the conjugation $xKx^{-1}$ is also a subgroup. The intersection of two subgroups $I:=H\cap xKx^{-1}$ is a subgroup of the group $H$. The number of left cosets of $H$ to $I$ is exactly $|H:I|=\frac{|H|}{|I|}$. Since $HxK=\bigcup_{h\in H}hxK$ and $\forall h\in H,\ |hxK|=|K|$, the cardinality of $HxK$ is a multiple of $|K|$. Let's say $|HxK|=r|K|$. Finally, we show that $r=|H:I|$  via the following bijective map.
$$f:\{hI:h\in H\}\to\{hxK:h\in H\}$$
$$hI\mapsto f(hI)=hxK$$
$f$ is well-defined and is injective (hence bijective) since for any $h,h^\prime\in H$,
$$hI=h^\prime I\Leftrightarrow h^{-1}h^\prime \in I\Leftrightarrow x^{-1}h^{-1}h^\prime x\in K\Leftrightarrow hxK=h^\prime xK$$Therefore,$$|HxK|=|H:I||K|=\frac{|H||K|}{|H\cap xKx^{-1}|}$$